# Defining Duplicate Child Elements in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to generate a DTD and I was wondering how to allow child elements to contain elements that have already been declared in the DTD. Do you have to declare them again? As an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE document [
  <!ELEMENT document (author,title,body)>
  <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT body (br*,hr*,img*,table*)>
  <!ELEMENT br EMPTY>
  <!ELEMENT hr EMPTY>
  <!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
  <!ELEMENT table (tr+)>
  <!ELEMENT tr (td+)>
  <!ELEMENT td (#PCDATA)>
```

<!--hr element-->
  <!ATTLIST hr width CDATA "0">

<!--img element-->
  <!ATTLIST img height CDATA "0">
  <!ATTLIST img src CDATA #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST img width CDATA "0">

<!--td element-->
  <!ATTLIST td width CDATA "0">
]>
<document>
  <author>My Author</author>
  <title>My Title Test</title>
  <body>
    <hr />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Would like elements here</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</document>

In the above XML, I'd like to, for example, allow the br, hr, img and table tags to be within the td tag. Do I have to redefine those elements in the DTD?

I appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should reference them in the `<!ELEMENT td>` definition

edit:
if you want to maintain the parsed character data in the td element along with the new tags, you can define a mixed content element.
example:

`<!ELEMENT td (#PCDATA | br? | hr? | img?)>`

see [element declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#elemdecls) at w3.org

Comment: Could you please elaborate, a little? The td element also needs to allow text. I'm not sure how to allow the referenced elements in addition to whatever text I might want to enter.